# What's a good spectrum analyzer to learn with?

Tags: spectrum-analyzer

I'm trying to learn more about building RF circuits and I want to buy a spectrum analyzer. I've looked around on ebay, and a lot of them are really expensive. I'm a student, so I don't have a lot of money to spend on it. What's a good model to buy since I'm just starting out?

Comment: How much have you got to spend? Bandwidth?

Comment: If you're a student, can you use one at your college?  Buying one is an extreme investment just to learn with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a spectrum analyser made from a [kid's toy](http://ossmann.blogspot.com/2010/03/16-pocket-spectrum-analyzer.html).

These are £4.99 in my local toy shop.

It's been handy for determining the operating frequencies of wireless sensors.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about this project! One of my friends also suggested that I just use an oscilloscope for low frequency stuff. If I build a transmitter that operates around like 1 MHz, then even if I'm off by a factor of 10, I can still see it. And simulating it is also a good idea. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

1. For learning, you are better off with the simulated spectrum analyzer in your simulation software.
2. For use, they are more similar than they are different, so I would worry about what is cheap.
3. Using one at school as @Nick T suggested is certainly cheaper than any one.